# How can I show output in % using this case condition in clickhouse db

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse

How can I show output in % using this case condition in clickhouse db.

```
ROUND(count(distinct case when bt.status = 'approved' then bt.id else null end)/count(distinct p.id) * 100) as "SR- txns"
```

Answer (score 0):

But it works as is????

```
create table test(id int, id2 int, status String) Engine=Memory
as select number,number, ['approved', 'completed'][number%3] from numbers(10);

select ROUND(count(distinct case when status = 'approved' then id else null end)/count(distinct id2) * 100) as "SR- txns"
from test
┌─SR- txns─┐
│       30 │
└──────────┘
```

Clickhouse flavored syntax:

```sql
select ROUND(uniqExactIf(id,status = 'approved')/uniqExact(id2) * 100) as "SR- txns"
from test
┌─SR- txns─┐
│       30 │
└──────────┘
```

Comment: Is it possible to check this question and help? Thank  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75594142/8519380